# securing laptop power cords

Tags: laptop, power-supply, cable, adapter

I have a new Dell Inspiron 14R (model N4010) laptop. I tend to keep it turned on and running on AC power. It's usually on my desk, but I like to be able to move to a different chair on the other side of the room. When I pick it up from the desk, the power cord frequently falls out. Sometimes the cord falls out if I move it slightly to a more convenient position on the desk.

I'd like to remove the battery to protect it from the heat, but right now it's the only thing preventing the excitement of unexpected power loss. Is there a way to secure the cord that's easily reversible? The answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/52975/dell-laptop-power-cable-always-falls-out) aren't too helpful, since it's about a stationary laptop and most of the solutions are rather permanent. Duct tape is always an option, but I'd like to avoid sticky residue on my laptop.

What are my other options? Would it be possible to replace the internal power jack and cord with something similar to a MagSafe connector?

Comment: Why is the heat an issue in this particular case? With the battery in place you have a UPS solution that doesn't require any [Heath Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) contraptions.

Comment: @ChrisF: Heating up batteries of some chemistries can reduce their life.

Comment: @Ignacio - equally some batteries have a shortened life if they are left discharged or not continually charged via a trickle current. I would assume (unless told otherwise) that a laptop battery was designed to be left in and cope with being continually charged.

Comment: As mentioned in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/77457/what-is-it-that-kills-laptop-batteries), heat is one of the major reasons lithium-ion batteries deteriorate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategic use of [these](http://www.command.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/NACommand/Command/Products/Product-Catalog/?PC_7_RJH9U523080QE0IIHEICN90GC1_nid=G8PXP48CGFgsG43WLKMM87gl3VJFR64SD2bl) might help.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I like it.